# iPhone - UITextAlignmentRight in UILabel cuts some part of text

Tags: iphone

I am trying to display two labels on UITableViewCell, one with left-aligned text and another with right-aligned text. The cell with right-alignment of text is cut on the right by 1-2 pixels. I tried increasing the width of the UILabel but it does not make a difference.

The text appear fine in the simulator but on the device it gets cut towards the right.

[Here's the image URL for reference](http://img516.imageshack.us/my.php?image=img1.jpg) (**Long Text 3** is cut)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This can be overcome by using the autoResizingMask property of the UILabel with right alignment.

```
label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20985086/3747951...here is the best answer to resolve this issue

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the right alignment clipping problem with labels in UITableViewCell is related to the font in use.

If you're just using numerics, simple fonts like system, Helvetica and Courier do not get clipped. However they do when in Oblique or BoldOblique.

"Fancier" fonts like Palatino get clipped on wide digits like zero and eight.

For letters, I've found that the wide ones like "W" always lose at least the leftmost pixel on a non retina display with proportional fonts including system and helvetica, but not with Courier.

So, if using numerics, use a basic font like system, Helvetica or Courier and avoid Obliques.
A workaround for any character in any font is to append a single space to the end of the string before assigning it to label.text.

The label.autoresizingMask may assist in some cases, but I did not find it to have any effect on this issue with labels in a UITableViewCell.

Tested in IOS 5.1