# UILabel clipping italic (oblique) text at left and right edges of content ( iOS 6+)

Tags: ios, ios7, uilabel, autolayout

**Problem:**
`UILabel` may clip italic (oblique) characters and even scripts at the left and right edges. The following screenshot displays the issue. At the left edge, the descender of the 'j' is clipped; at the right edge, the ascender of the 'l' is clipped. I realize this is subtle, and not everyone is going to care (however, the issue gets worse with larger font sizes).

[image]

Here's a less subtle example using Zapfino, size 22. Note the 'j' in jupiter looks almost like an 'i':

[image]

In the examples above, the background color of the label is orange, the text is left aligned, and the label maintains its intrinsic content size.

This is the default behavior of a `UILabel` and its been that way for multiple versions of iOS (so I'm not expecting a fix from Apple).

**What I have tried:**
Setting the label's `clipsToBounds` property to `NO` does not resolve the issue. I'm also aware that I could set a fixed width constraint on the label to give the text more room at the trailing edge. However, a fixed width constraint would not give the 'j', in the example above, more room.

I'm going to answer my own question using a solution that leverages *Auto Layout* and the label's `alignmentRectInsets`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The top label shows the default behavior of a `UILabel` when the text is left aligned that the label maintains its intrinsic content size. The bottom label is a simple (almost trivial) subclass of `UILabel`. The bottom label does not clip the 'j' or the 'l'; instead, it gives the text some room to breathe at the left and right edges without center aligning the text (yuck).

[image]

Although the labels themselves don't appear aligned on screen, their text does appear aligned; and what's more, in IB, the labels actually have their left edges aligned because I override `alignmentRectInsets` in a `UILabel` subclass.

[image]

Here's the code that configures the two labels:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "NonClippingLabel.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *topLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NonClippingLabel *bottomLabel;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *string = @"jupiter ariel";

    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-BoldOblique" size:28];

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: font};

    NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attributes];

    self.topLabel.attributedText = attrString;
    self.bottomLabel.attributedText = attrString;     
}
```

Here's the implementation of the `NonClippingLabel` subclass:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NonClippingLabel : UILabel

@end

@implementation NonClippingLabel

#define GUTTER 4.0f // make this large enough to accommodate the largest font in your app

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // fixes word wrapping issue
    CGRect newRect = rect;
    newRect.origin.x = rect.origin.x + GUTTER;
    newRect.size.width = rect.size.width - 2 * GUTTER;
    [self.attributedText drawInRect:newRect];
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)alignmentRectInsets
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, GUTTER, 0, GUTTER);
}

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    CGSize size = [super intrinsicContentSize];
    size.width += 2 * GUTTER;
    return size;
}

@end
```

No editing a font file, no using Core Text; just a relatively simple `UILabel` subclass for those using iOS 6+ and Auto Layout.

**Update:**

Augie caught the fact that my original solution prevented word wrapping for multi-lined text. I fixed that issue by using `drawInRect:` instead of `drawAtPoint:` to draw the text in the label's `drawRect:` method.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

The top label is a plain-vanilla `UILabel`. The bottom label is a `NonClippingLabel` with an extreme gutter setting to accommodate Zapfino at size 22.0. Both labels are left and right aligned using Auto Layout.

[image]

Comment: this is great, but it breaks line wrapping

Comment: @Augie Thanks for catching the word-wrapping issue. See my update for a fix.

Comment: Super answer! If you like me have a problem with vertical clipping with characters like ÅÄÖ then swap the width for height and x for y in the code

Comment: important note. you should modify method `sizeThatFits` in case you want `sizeToFit` work properly, otherwise the content will be truncated after sending `sizeToFit`. Here is the code:  `-(CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size
{

    CGSize size_ = [super sizeThatFits:size];
    size_.width += 2 * GUTTER;
    return size_;
}`

Comment: fantastic answer, implemented with @purrrminator 's method as I use `sizeToFit`, works perfectly, thanks both!!

Answer (score 4):

Swift version of `NonClippingLabel` with fixed `sizeThatFits` method from bilobatum answer.

```
class NonClippingLabel: UILabel {
    
    let gutter: CGFloat = 4
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: rect.insetBy(dx: gutter, dy: 0))
    }
    
    override var alignmentRectInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        return .init(top: 0, left: gutter, bottom: 0, right: gutter)
    }
    
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        if #available(iOS 17, *) {
            // From iOS 17 onwards, it seems that when alignmentRectInsets changes, intrinsicContentSize automatically changes as well, so don't increase the intrinsicContentSize for iOS 17 and later.
            return super.intrinsicContentSize
        }
        var size = super.intrinsicContentSize
        size.width += gutter * 2
        
        return size
    }
    
    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let fixedSize = CGSize(width: size.width - 2 * gutter, height: size.height)
        let sizeWithoutGutter = super.sizeThatFits(fixedSize)
        
        return CGSize(width: sizeWithoutGutter.width + 2 * gutter,
                      height: sizeWithoutGutter.height)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having to go thru a bunch of gymnastics to work around this silly Apple bug (which I did), a quick-and-dirty hack is just add a **space** to the end of your string to stop the last italic letter being clipped. Obviously doesn't help with multi-line labels alas, or clipped first letter descender...

Comment: This was enough for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift** and **SwiftUI** version based on Vadim Akhmerov and bilobatum's answers. All four edges are now customizable and can be changed/updated.

Also hosted as a Github Gist: https://gist.github.com/ryanlintott/2340f35977bf2d1f7b6ea40aa379bcc6

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct NoClipText: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = NoClipLabel
    
    let text: String
    let font: UIFont
    let clipExtension: EdgeSizes

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIViewType {
        let uiView = UIViewType()
        uiView.text = text
        uiView.font = font
        uiView.clipExtension = clipExtension
        return uiView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        uiView.font = font
        uiView.clipExtension = clipExtension
    }
}

class NoClipLabel: UILabel {
    static let defaultClipExtension: EdgeSizes = .all(10)
    
    var clipExtension: EdgeSizes
    
    var top: CGFloat { clipExtension.top }
    var left: CGFloat { clipExtension.left }
    var bottom: CGFloat { clipExtension.bottom }
    var right: CGFloat { clipExtension.right }
    var width: CGFloat { left + right }
    var height: CGFloat { bottom + top }
    
    required init(clipExtension: EdgeSizes = defaultClipExtension) {
        self.clipExtension = clipExtension
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        clipExtension = Self.defaultClipExtension
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        clipExtension = Self.defaultClipExtension
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: top, left: left, bottom: bottom, right: right)))
    }

    override var alignmentRectInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        return .init(top: top, left: left, bottom: bottom, right: right)
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var size = super.intrinsicContentSize
        size.width += width
        size.height += height

        return size
    }

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let fixedSize = CGSize(width: size.width - width, height: size.height - height)
        let sizeWithoutExtension = super.sizeThatFits(fixedSize)

        return CGSize(width: sizeWithoutExtension.width + width,
                      height: sizeWithoutExtension.height + height)
    }

}

struct EdgeSizes: Equatable {
    let top: CGFloat
    let left: CGFloat
    let bottom: CGFloat
    let right: CGFloat
    
    init(top: CGFloat = 0, left: CGFloat = 0, bottom: CGFloat = 0, right: CGFloat = 0) {
        self.top = top
        self.left = left
        self.bottom = bottom
        self.right = right
    }
    
    init(vertical: CGFloat = 0, horizontal: CGFloat = 0) {
        self.top = vertical
        self.left = horizontal
        self.bottom = vertical
        self.right = horizontal
    }
    
    init(_ all: CGFloat) {
        self.top = all
        self.left = all
        self.bottom = all
        self.right = all
    }
    
    static let zero = EdgeSizes(0)
    
    static func all(_ size: CGFloat) -> EdgeSizes {
        EdgeSizes(size)
    }
    
    static func vertical(_ size: CGFloat) -> EdgeSizes {
        EdgeSizes(vertical: size)
    }
    
    static func horizontal(_ size: CGFloat) -> EdgeSizes {
        EdgeSizes(horizontal: size)
    }
}
```