# Text with custom font truncated

Tags: ios, swiftui, layout, fonts

I use the custom font "Zapfino" in my app, but the texts sometimes get truncated as shown in the picture below. Usually the text frame (colored red below) automatically expands with the contained text - but this does not seem to work for (some) custom fonts:

```
Text(name)
    .font(Font.custom("Zapfino", size: 48, relativeTo: .title))
    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    .baselineOffset(48)
    .padding(10)
    .background(Color.red)
```

[image: Example text "Test-f" which appears truncated]

Any ideas how to fix this? I tried to set the frame size explicitly, but it did not work.

Comment: Zapfino is notorious for unruly character / glyph bounding boxes. Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20985085/uilabel-clipping-italic-oblique-text-at-left-and-right-edges-of-content-ios -- specifically for your case, this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64565207/6257435

Comment: Thanks for that hint - that's exactly my problem. Re: the solution I need somehow to adopt it to work with SwiftUI I suppose. Using the suggested code has some side effects so far (it does not return a Text, justification, coloring and automatic text truncation does not work anymore...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to adjust the SwiftUI related code from [stackoverflow.com/a/64565207/6257435](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64565207/6257435) to my needs. In order to enable automatic truncation of the text I defined a maximum intrinsic size that is considered accordingly:

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    var size = super.intrinsicContentSize
    size.width = min(size.width + clipExtension.width, maxIntrinsicContentSize.width)
    size.height = min(size.height + clipExtension.height, maxIntrinsicContentSize.height)
    return size
}
```

Otherwise the intrinsic size always extended to the text length and thus the text was never truncated.